# Show that the set $\{(x_1,x_2) : 4 \sqrt{x_1} + x_2 \geq 20\}$ is a convex set.

Tags: multivariable-calculus, convex-analysis, convex-optimization

> Suppose $f : \mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}$ is given by $f(x_1,x_2) = 4 \sqrt{x_1} + x_2$. Show that the set $\{(x_1,x_2) : f(x_1,x_2) \geq 20\}$ is a convex set.

---

We need to show that for any $x = (a,b)$ and $y= (c,d)$ satisfying $\min\{f(x), f(y)\} \geq 20$, $$f(\theta x + (1-\theta)y) \geq 20 \quad \forall\; \theta \in [0,1]$$

How can we show that $4 \sqrt{a} + b \geq 20$ and $4 \sqrt{c} + d \geq 20$ together imply that

$$f(\theta x + (1-\theta)y) = 4 \sqrt{\theta a + (1 - \theta)c} + \theta b + (1-\theta)d \geq 20$$ for all $\theta \in [0,1]$?

Comment: I suppose that it is a subset of $[0,\infty)\times\Bbb R$ rather than a subset of $\Bbb R^2$.

Comment: There's absolutely no context. Just to commands and a question about how "we show" something.  No input whatsoever from you.  Please explain what you do not understand, what you've worked and specifically, where you get stuck.  Or, what is the source of this question, and what motivates you to ask it?

Comment: The main point is to prove that $\sqrt{\theta x+(1-\theta)y}\ge \theta \sqrt{x}+(1-\theta)\sqrt{y}.$ This can be shown by the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality.

Comment: There is a simpler approach: It is the epigraph of the convex function $f(x) = 20-4 \sqrt{x}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem boils down to showing: $\sqrt{\theta x+(1-\theta)y}\ge \theta\sqrt{x}+(1-\theta)\sqrt{y}$ as suggested by @Ryszard Szwarc in the comment line above. Apply Cauchy-Schwarz inequality: $\theta\sqrt{x}+(1-\theta)\sqrt{y}=\sqrt{\theta}\sqrt{\theta x}+\sqrt{1-\theta}\sqrt{(1-\theta)y}\le \sqrt{(\theta + (1-\theta))(\theta x+(1-\theta)y)}=\sqrt{\theta x+(1-\theta)y}$. From this you have: $4\sqrt{\theta a+(1-\theta)c}+\theta b + (1-\theta)d \ge 4(\theta\sqrt{a}+(1-\theta)\sqrt{c})+\theta b+(1-\theta)d= \theta(4\sqrt{a}+b)+(1-\theta)(4\sqrt{c}+d)\ge 20\theta+20(1-\theta)=20.$, proving the set convex.

Answer (score 1):

The domain mentioned is the [supergraph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Epigraph_(mathematics)) of the function $x_1 \mapsto 20 - 4 \sqrt{x_1}$ from $[0, infty)$ to $\mathbb{R}$. Notice that this function is convex.

Obs: The function $f(x_1, x_2) = 4 \sqrt{x_1} + x_2$ is in fact concave ( sum of two concave functions), and therefore, all its superlevel sets are convex.

Note: One can consider the case of a function that is not concave, yet its superlevel sets are convex. For instance, the function $f\colon (0, \infty)\times \ldots \times (0, \infty) \to (0, \infty)$, $f(x_1, \ldots, x_n) = x_1 \cdots x_n$. Now this function $f$ is quasiconcave. Indeed, say we have two points $(x_1, \ldots, x_n)$, and $(y_1, \ldots, y_n)$ with $\prod x_i$, $\prod y_i\ge a$. We get
$$\prod \frac{x_i+y_i}{2} \ge \prod \sqrt{x_i y_i} \ge \sqrt{a}^2 = a$$. The question is whether the function $f$ is in fact concave. Let's see the case $n=2$. Is it true that
$$\frac{x_1 x_2}{2} + \frac{y_1 y_2}{2} \le \frac{x_1+y_1}{2} \cdot \frac{x_2 + y_2}{2}$$
That depends on the ordering of $x_i$, $y_i$, so it's not always true. Thus, $f$ is quasi-concave, but not concave.